# Is it Possible to take Picture (without save to external or internal storage) and Crop it?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-bundle

I post my code here, which,
First save the captured image to the local directory and
Fetch it from directory and crop. I need to CAPTURE THE IMAGE AND IMMEDIATELY CROP IT THEN SAVE. 
Is it possible to save the captured image in Bundle/Intent Extra and then Invoke the Crop Function?

```
camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "img.jpg");

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "img.jpg");

        try {

            cropCapturedImage(Uri.fromFile(file));
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException aNFE){

            String errorMessage = "Sorry - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    if(requestCode==2){

        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");


        proofImage.setImageBitmap(thePic);
    }
}

public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri){

    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
}
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: I don't need cropping libraries. i want to crop an image without saving it, i want to save that after cropping. any idea?

Comment: "I don't need cropping libraries" -- if you want to crop images, you need a cropping library, or to write your own cropping library. There are ~2 billion Android devices, spanning thousands of device models. None have to have support for `com.android.camera.action.CROP`, and none of the handful that *do* support it have to support some means for you to crop from memory.

Comment: Actually my question is not regarding to crop images, before passing image to cropping library or code i don't need to save that image. is there any way to do that ?

Comment: "is there any way to do that ?" -- use the camera APIs yourself. Or, implement a `ContentProvider` that attempts to hold the entire photo in memory, and use a `content` scheme `Uri` pointing to that provider with `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. However, not all camera apps support `content` `Uri` values there (though they should), and I would expect you to run out of memory a *lot* when trying to hold onto the photo.

Comment: Thank you for your replay :). so the safe way is SAVE before CROP?(memory,camera api)
then after cropping delete the saved file!! i am taking photo of documents in my application. thats why i bother too much for saving the picture.

Comment: "so the safe way is SAVE before CROP?(memory,camera api) then after cropping delete the saved file!" -- correct. Full-resolution photos are *huge* in terms of memory (four bytes * width in pixels * height in pixels).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either ways :

1. Using intent to open camera and take pictures and crop it using **glide**
2. You can pick images from a URL instead of URI and crop it using **glide**

   ***Glide.with(this).load(value)
                       .crossFade()
                       .thumbnail(0.5f)
                       .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                       .into(callerimg);***

You could use  .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this)) to shape in circle. Here CircleTransform is a class which shape picked image in a circle.